# KeyError: 'vendor_id' when installing packages

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, keyerror

I am attempting to carry out lens correction and I've fallen at the first hurdle. After running the following code, I receive this error...

```
#Install required packages

!pip install opencv-python
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pathlib
!pip install chessboard
from chessboard import calibrate_chessboard
from utils import load_coefficients, save_coefficients

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-0a40b3424bef> in <module>()
      6 import pathlib
      7 get_ipython().system('pip install chessboard')
----> 8 from chessboard import calibrate_chessboard
      9 from utils import load_coefficients, save_coefficients

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/chessboard/benchmark.py in Benchmark()
    105         ('machine', platform.machine()),
    106         # CPU.
--> 107         ('cpu_vendor', cpu_info['vendor_id']),
    108         ('cpu_model', cpu_info['brand']),
    109         ('cpu_freq_actual', cpu_info['hz_actual'][0]),

KeyError: 'vendor_id'
```

Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are using [outdated package `chessboard`, not updated since 2017](https://pypi.org/project/chessboard/), repo now archived.

[It rely on](https://github.com/kdeldycke/chessboard/blob/3bd82beb6198730cf337335421712732a90f0fc0/setup.py#L46) another package [py-cpuinfo](https://pypi.org/project/py-cpuinfo/). There is [this issue](https://github.com/workhorsy/py-cpuinfo/issues/112). The key `vendor_id` is now replaced with `vendor_id_raw`. Note that setup.py for chessboard [does not specify version](https://github.com/kdeldycke/chessboard/blob/3bd82beb6198730cf337335421712732a90f0fc0/setup.py#L46) for `py-cpuinfo`, so I guess you use the latest one.

One way to solve the problem is to use specific older version of py-cpuinfo before that change. The latest version of `py-cpuinfo` with `vendor_id` is 5.0.0. The latest version before latest `chessboard` release date is 3.3.0

Another option is to try and replace key `vendor_id` with `vendor_id_raw` everywhere inside `chessbeoard` package.

My preference would be with the second option as `chessboard` is no longer developed. In any case be aware there might be other issues or unwanted behaviour.

Comment: I had difficulty finding the package details online which made me think it wasn't available. I will make the changes as you suggestion - thanks for your help!

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/py-cpuinfo/#history

Comment: The latest version of `py-cpuinfo` with `vendor_id` is 5.0.0. The latest version before latest `chessboard` update date is 3.3.0